# MySQL INNER JOIN Multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table1: violations
Columns: date, time, pdid, pname, v1, v2, v3, v4

Each v1 through v4 has an integer value which corresponds to a single entry (ID) in table 2.

table2:  parking_violations
columns: code, section, description, ID

I need to query each record of violations based on pdid, and match each 'v1-v4' to column 'ID' in the p_violations table.

```
SELECT 
    parking.date,
    parking.time,
    parking.pname,
    parking_violations.code,
    parking_violations.section,
    parking_violations.description
FROM 
    parking
INNER JOIN parking_violations ON parking.v1=parking_violations.ID
WHERE 
    pdid=5
```

This returns the correct records for V1, but I cannot figure out how to also return V2-V4 all populated by matching the value to ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @fa06 explain, you can use multiple joins to the same table, but instead of **inner join** i will use **left join**, this way i have the flexibility of get rows where not all **vN** have matching IDs on the table parking_violations.

```
SELECT 
    parking.date,
    parking.time,
    parking.pname,
    pv1.code,
    pv1.section,
    pv1.description,
    pv2.code,
    pv2.section,
    pv2.description,
    pv3.code,
    pv3.section,
    pv3.description,
    pv4.code,
    pv4.section,
    pv4.description
FROM
    parking
LEFT JOIN
    parking_violations AS pv1 ON pv1.ID = parking.v1
LEFT JOIN
    parking_violations AS pv2 ON pv2.ID = parking.v2
LEFT JOIN
    parking_violations AS pv3 ON pv3.ID = parking.v3
LEFT JOIN
    parking_violations AS pv4 ON pv4.ID = parking.v4
WHERE 
    parking.pdid = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

use join multiple time with alias like below:

```
SELECT 
    parking.date,
    parking.time,
    parking.pname,
    parking_violations.code,
    parking_violations.section,
    parking_violations.description
FROM 
    parking
INNER JOIN parking_violations ON parking.v1=parking_violations.ID
inner join parking_violations a ON parking.v2=a.ID
inner join parking_violations b ON parking.v3=b.ID
inner join parking_violations c ON parking.v4=d.ID
WHERE 
    pdid=5
```

Comment: Thank you fa06, that got me a lot closer!  But how do I deal with V2-V4 if empty? V1 is always populated, but V2-V4 can be empty.

Comment: could you please show what is your expected output - then it will be more clear to me for answering your question

Comment: Thank you fa06, you were very helpful.  I wish I could have accepted both.